# MySQL mentor student table

Tags: mysql, database

This is te problem, 
I have a database with a table called Users with 3 columns UserID Mentor and Name, I want to show the users and their mentors. and if i do it like this:

```
SELECT UserID, mentorID, Name
FROM Users;
```

I will get this:

```
| UserID | Mentor | Name
| 1      | NULL     | Walter
| 2      | 1        | Jesse
| 3      | 1        | Todd
```

But I want to get it like this:

```
| UserID | Mentor | Name
| 1      | NULL   | Walter
| 2      | Walter | Jesse
| 3      | Walter | Todd
```

Thanks for helping, 
have a nice day :)

P.S. 
The real database a bit more complex but i simplify it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self join  ( a join with the same table)

```
select a.userID, a.Name as user_name , a.mentorID, b.Name as mentor_name
from user a
left join user b on a.mentorID = b.userID
```

Comment: Thank you so much you just saved my school project <3

Comment: @merlijnmerlinberg    suggest you study more thoroughly SQL and the relational model .. is not difficult  .. thinks always in terms of Set Theory

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you need to use self join(A self join is a join in which a table is joined with itself) --

```
SELECT u.UserID, m.Name AS mentor, u.Name FROM user as u LEFT JOIN user AS m ON u.MentorID = m.UserID
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. Consider using a few  line breaks and some whitespace, in code and prose,  to format your answer more readably.